# Please clarify how to use Framework7 ajax (to trigger server side processing)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, html-framework-7

please can someone clarify what I need to do in a framework7/node-js app to trigger a server-side function from client-side? I want a server side script (coded by me) to compile a json file and send me back the name/url before I request that new json file from server side to client side.

This link shows "Request/ajax" in framework7 documentation [1]: https://framework7.io/docs/request.html
But there is nothing that I could find about specifying a response.

I can use the below function to get a static already existing json file/data from the server:

```
//below code placed inside 'pageInit' block 
//in the code block 'var app = new Framework7({ })'
//in app.js file

app.request.get("/assets/datafile.json", function (data){ 
   
    //turn json data into a javascript object
    var mobj = JSON.parse(data);
}
```

I've tried to use node_modules, but the function 'require(module)' which is used to import modules is not available to use from client side files...

I selected 'include bundler' in the npm set up of the project directory, and now I'm working with 'vite'. So I can't find a server file to edit if needed.

I've become confused as how to fetch dynamic data in this situation. I've read online to use a XMLHttprequest on a server side API, I've read you have to wrap the server side code in a 'route', I've read you have to change the server file code, I've read you can use a php script, but I haven't been able to make this thing work with Framework7.

If anyone knows how to do this, please give us a hint. Thanks.

Comment: framework 7 is a client-side framework.  You also need to write an actual node.js backend. I recommend using express, the go-to web server framework. The counterpart to the code above, using express, would be something like `app.get("/assets/datafile.json", (req, res) => { /* do stuff */ res.json(dataObject); });` See here: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/installing.html

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'm assuming both the function above and the (req,res) function could exist in the project directory. I'll look into the documentation...

Comment: You can put the server and the client in a single project folder, yes. You don't have to though. You could use any other backend for this. Client-side requests don't care which language or project they're getting the response from :)

Comment: I see. many thanks.